# Tomcat still send "Continue 100" when no request body sending. Like 401 unauthenticated case

Tags: tomcat, servlets

Tomcat send 100 also for 401 unauthenticated case, which no body is sending actually.
According to [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-8.2.3), the server should either 100, or the actual status code (401 in this case) when no body is reading, but not both.

It seems violation of RFC definition.
Can we change the tomcat behavior to be same with RFC definition?

Requirements for HTTP/1.1 origin servers:

```
  - Upon receiving a request which includes an Expect request-header
    field with the "100-continue" expectation, an origin server MUST
    either respond with 100 (Continue) status and continue to read
    from the input stream, or respond with a final status code. The
    origin server MUST NOT wait for the request body before sending
    the 100 (Continue) response. If it responds with a final status
    code, it MAY close the transport connection or it MAY continue
    to read and discard the rest of the request.  It MUST NOT
    perform the requested method if it returns a final status code.
```

Here is the wireshark log:
[image]

Comment: You are looking at an outdated rfc. The correct rfc is https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.2.1 and the observed behaviour does  not violate it.

Comment: Even for rfc7231, there is still similar definition.    
An origin server MUST, upon receiving an HTTP/1.1 (or later)
   request-line and a complete header section that contains a
   100-continue expectation and indicates a request message body will
   follow, either send an immediate response with a final status code,
   if that status can be determined by examining just the request-line
   and header fields, or send an immediate 100 (Continue) response to
   encourage the client to send the request's message body.

Comment: yeah, so it sends 100, receives the request body, then sends 401 which is completely in line with the rfc, no ?

Comment: From the definition, it should either send an immediate response with a final status code (no 100 is needed)
, or send 100 and continue sending the body.

Comment: The case is it didn't receive the request body and still send 100. In this case, I guess 100 is not needed since request body will not be received.

Answer (score -1):

This is a Tomcat bug. The correct response header is '100 continue' instead of '100' . It is recommended that you change a web application server.